# Faster way to put formula into Range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that sets the formula of the Range. It works on small Range but if the range gets more than 1000 it executes very slow

Also `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` does not work

Here is the setup:
I have column A where I paste Emails or Passwords.
I then click a button to run my Macro to Check if the Email or Password is Valid and Return True or False only to the Rows that have values.

Here is my Code:

```
Sub ValEmail()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim lastRow As String
Dim useRange As String
Dim cel As Range
Dim validEmail As Range
Dim rnum As Integer

'Gets the Last Row Used
rnum = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

lastRow = "F" & rnum

'Set the Range where formula will be put
useRange = "F2" & ":" & lastRow

Set validEmail = Range(useRange)

'Put formula into Range
validEmail.Formula = "=IsEmailValid(A2)"

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True
End Sub
```

My code works but it is very slow most especially if I have 10k + Rows with Values. Even if there are only 200 Rows it is very slow.

Edit, here is my IsEmailValid Code:

```
Function IsEmailValid(strEmail)

Dim strArray As Variant
Dim strItem As Variant
Dim i As Long, c As String, blnIsItValid As Boolean
blnIsItValid = True

i = Len(strEmail) - Len(Application.Substitute(strEmail, "@", ""))
If i <> 1 Then IsEmailValid = False: Exit Function
ReDim strArray(1 To 2)
strArray(1) = Left(strEmail, InStr(1, strEmail, "@", 1) - 1)
strArray(2) = Application.Substitute(Right(strEmail, Len(strEmail) - Len(strArray(1))), "@", "")
For Each strItem In strArray
    If Len(strItem) <= 0 Then
        blnIsItValid = False
        IsEmailValid = blnIsItValid
        Exit Function
    End If
    For i = 1 To Len(strItem)
        c = LCase(Mid(strItem, i, 1))
        If InStr("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'_-.", c) <= 0 And Not IsNumeric(c) Then
            blnIsItValid = False
            IsEmailValid = blnIsItValid
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    If Left(strItem, 1) = "." Or Right(strItem, 1) = "." Then
        blnIsItValid = False
        IsEmailValid = blnIsItValid
        Exit Function
    End If
Next strItem
If InStr(strArray(2), ".") <= 0 Then
    blnIsItValid = False
    IsEmailValid = blnIsItValid
    Exit Function
End If
i = Len(strArray(2)) - InStrRev(strArray(2), ".")
If i <> 2 And i <> 3 Then
    blnIsItValid = False
    IsEmailValid = blnIsItValid
    Exit Function
End If
If InStr(strEmail, "..") > 0 Then
    blnIsItValid = False
    IsEmailValid = blnIsItValid
    Exit Function
End If
IsEmailValid = blnIsItValid

End Function
```

Comment: Can you you provide code for IsEmailValid. as this might be consuming a lot of time.

Comment: Actually this should be quite the fastest way. While the code could be shortened a bit, that would not improve speed noticible. As omaril already said, it looks like your `IsEmailValid` function is using a lot of time. The problem is not in the code you posted but in the code of `IsEmailValid`. If `IsEmailValid` needs only 1 second to analyze 1 cell it is already 1000 seconds for 1000 cells. So here is the issue. [Edit] your question and add the code of `IsEmailValid`.

Comment: I have edited my Question and added my IsEmailValid Function. Though it only takes fraction of a second to execute if used on the Cell itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function `IsEmailValid` instead of yours:

```
Public Function IsEmailValid(ByVal EmailAddress As String) As Boolean
    Dim RegEx As Object
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    With RegEx
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "^((\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)\s*[;]{0,1}\s*)+$"
    End With

    IsEmailValid = RegEx.test(EmailAddress)
End Function
```

Alternative RegEx for emails can be found here: https://emailregex.com

---

```
Public Sub ValEmail()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    On Error GoTo CATCH
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim validEmail As Range
    Set validEmail = Range("F2", "F" & LastRow)

    validEmail.Formula = "=IsEmailValid(A2)"

    On Error Goto 0

CATCH:
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
        Err.Clear
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks man. This worked faster than my previous code. Though I replaced "validEmail.Formula = "=IsEmailValid(A2)" to With function.

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't something like this work? I've tried to make a shorter version.

```
Sub valEmail()

    Dim rnum As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False    

    With ActiveSheet

    rnum = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("F2").Formula = "=isemailvalid(A2)"
    Range("F2").Copy Destination:=Range("F3" & ":" & "F" & rnum)

    End with

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```